# How to send data from one component to another component in react without parent child relation

Tags: reactjs

Home Component

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import Two from 'components/Two.jsx'
    import One from 'components/One.jsx'

    class Home extends Component {
      constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {

        }
         this.one = React.createRef();
      }

      getData = (data) => {
        this.one.current.finalClick(data);
      }

      render() {
        return (
            <div>
              <Two shareData={this.getData} />
              <One ref={this.one} />
            </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default Home;
```

One Compoent:

```
    import React from 'react'

    class One extends React.Component {
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state={

            }
        }

        finalClick = (data) => {
            console.log(data)
        }

        render(){
            return (
                <div>

                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    export default One;
```

Two Component:

```
    import React from 'react'

    class Two extends React.Component {
        handleClick = (data) => {
            this.props.shareData(data)
        }

        render(){
            return (
                <div>
                    <br/>
                    <button className="btn btn-info" onClick={() => this.handleClick('hellow')}>click</button>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    export default Two;
```

Here i am tring to get click one function from from another components.
which is not it's parent or child componet.

First I am clicking the button in two and it is sending data to Home Component.
And it is logging the data.

And i wants to send data to **finalClick()** method in the same time after **getData()** called in Home Component.

My **finalClick()** function in **One** Component getting clicked but data is not going.

Comment: You will need to have  shared parent somewhere. See https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Answer (score 0):

Save the data that you want to share in the state of `Home`. Pass a function from `Home` to `Two` through `Two`'s props in order to update the data. Pass the data from `Home`'s state down to `One` in the props.